# How to test a 503 custom error page.

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

A rather strange question:

How can I test a custom 503 error page without restarting the service.

(Struts application on tomcat with apache front loading)

"What I really want is some how SIMULATE that the tomcat crashed, and apache as the front end will grab the error page, and redirect to the custom error page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Servlet which you exclude from production builds. This Servlet examines a parameter (e.g. errorCode) and sets it using the HTTP Servlet Response object: `javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int, java.lang.String)`.

Then you are able to test all kinds of error codes, e.g.:

`http://myapp.com/webapp/errorServlet?503`

Not nice, but should work... if you want to unit test your Apache Web Server only you could create a separate WAR file (depends on your test scope).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use curl?

```
   curl -H http://your/path/to/503page
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, after looking into the man page, I tried  curl -H 503 http://your/path/to/503page, It just return all the html in that page. But so does curl -H 503 http://your/path/to/okpage. What I really want is some how SIMULATE that the tomcat crashed, and apache as the front end will grab the error page, and redirect to the custom error page.

Comment: Well in that case -- your web server have to *actually* return a 503 error, so somehow you need to shutdown your backend, or mis-configure the webserver so that is cannot reach the backend resources.